# How to set a transparent winform, into a panel transparent panel, to show as background what's behind?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, panel

I'm coding a program which has a principal form with a pictureBox that i use as a common background image, i also use a panel, who has the pictureBox as a Parent, and I use that panel to join my other winforms in it, lets call this winforms "A" , my problem is that i set the A winforms as Transparent, so i can see the pictureBox that is behind the panel, now, my problem resides that when i join the A winforms, they show as transparent, but with the issue that the don't show the pictureBox, they show what's behind the program.

[This is the PictureBox that i want to show behind the A winforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol9rV.jpg)

[This is what I'm talking about, as you cab see, the program is showing me my own desktop wallpaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvuSD.png)

Please I need your help, as you can realise, as you can realise, my english is not so good, so i'm 
apologizing myself in advance. :)

Comment: The built-in Winforms transparency is not what you need in this case.  You need to look into [Layered windows](https://www.google.com/search?q=setlayeredwindowattributes&oq=SetLayeredWindowAttributes)

Comment: How are you achieving the transparency?

Answer (score 0):

To set the form's background, you don't need to add the `PictureBox`. You only need to set its `BackgroundImage Property`.

```
this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"D://pic/b.jpg");
```

Then set Panel to transparent.

```
panel1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

To set FormA to transparent, also need to call `SetStyle` in constructor.

```
public FormA()
{
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Here is the simple demo.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormA formA = new FormA();
    formA.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    formA.TopLevel = false;
    formA.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panel1.Controls.Add(formA);
    formA.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    formA.Show();
}
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I really apreciate it, the  main problem is that i only want to show part of picture where the panel is, not the hole pic again

Comment: @JuanManuelCasellA Do you mean that you only want to see the background image in the Panel section? Perhaps using other Panels to cover the rest is the easiest way.